# Is it possible to run Prometheus and Grafana docker containers but use node-exporter installed in the host machine?

Tags: devops, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I am trying to build a monitoring system with Prometheus, Grafana, and node exporter. I have a docker-compose file that spins up the Prometheus and Grafana containers but not node-exporter. According to [Node exporter GitHub documentation](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter), it is not recommended to deploy node-exporter as a container because it requires access to the host system.

Is it possible to use the Node exporter installed in the host machine alongside my docker-compose? If yes, what additional configs do I need to add?

Answer (score -1):

There is a good guide is [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/node-exporter/). One thing to note is that `node_exporter` is built for linux/bsd. If you are running your compose file on windows you would need to run the [windows_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus-community/windows_exporter). The process below would be different, but similar in theory.

to summarize the guide, download the specific/latest release and run the app:

```
wget https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/releases/download/v*/node_exporter-*.*-amd64.tar.gz 
tar xvfz node_exporter-*.*-amd64.tar.gz 
cd node_exporter-*.*-amd64 
./node_exporter
```

you should be able to access it over port `9100` on your host machine.

```
curl http://localhost:9100/metrics
```

then setup you `prometheus.yml` file (that you have backed into your docker image, or are bind mounting through docker-compose) like:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:
- job_name: node
  static_configs:
  - targets: ['<host ip/fqdn name:9100']
```

When you run the `node_exporter` script you can pass it a list of [collectors](https://github.com/prometheus-community/windows_exporter) you want to enable/disable. As you tune your monitoring system you will find metrics that you want to track and some that just are not helpful. You can save some overhead by removing collectors that your monitoring system is not going to use.

Comment: If Prometheus is running inside a container, scraping `localhost:9100` will not work, because that will be the address of the container, not the address of the host machine where `node_exporter` is running.